# Clicking on checkbox hides all elements with certain title

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, checkbox

I want when I check 1 checkbox all other checkboxes become unchecked but also every element with certain title in in to hide/show.

```
$('.chb').click(function() {
    var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.chb').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $('[title="+input_id+"]').show;
    $('[title!="+input_id+"]').hide;
});
```

I have this.

When I click on checkbox with class `.chb` I want uncheck all other but also that elements with `title=ID OF CHECKBOX` become visible and every other become invisible.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Why don't you use **radio buttons**? That's what they are made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have something like this

```
$('.chb').click(function() {
                                      var input_id = this.id;
                                      $('.chb').prop('checked', false);
                                      $(this).prop('checked', true);
                                      $('li[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();
                                      $('li[title="'+ input_id + '"]').show();
                                    });
```

```
                            });
<li class="clan" title="<?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?>">
                            <a class="noselect"><?php the_field('naziv',$page->ID); ?></a>

                            <div class="clan_content">
                                some cotent

                            </div>
                        </li>
```

And I want when i click on that checkbox, only corresponding li will show, when i click on another, it will hide and another will show. When I click on same li, I want everything to be visible again.

Edit: problem is somewhere in id. If i set var input_id = "NewYork"; its working just for that city, but if i change id of checkbox to NewYork from newyork its not working...

Comment: have you solved this problem? (uncheck and display all) check my updated answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. use the following to insert variable you need close the `'` first then use `+ input_id +` and open the single quote again:

   `$('span[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();`

   `$('span[title="'+ input_id + '"]').show();`
2. call function should be `hide()` and `show()`
3. Another approach will be using `radio` button (thanks to @Roko C. Buljan from the comments), as you can see in option 2 you don't need to uncheck and check manually.

#### *UPDATED: both checkbox and radio will support uncheck.*

### Option 1: checkbox version

```js
$('.chb').click(function() {
  var input_id = this.id;
  var _this = $(this);
  
  //uncheck, show everything
  if (!this.checked) {
    $('span').show();
    _this.siblings().prop('checked', false);
  } else {
  //check, show selected, hide others
    $('span[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();
    $('span[title="' + input_id + '"]').show();
    _this.toggle(this.checked);
    _this.siblings().prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="1" id="1" class="chb">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="2" id="2" class="chb">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="3" id="3" class="chb">3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="4" id="4" class="chb">4<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="5" id="5" class="chb">5<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="6" id="6" class="chb">6
</form>

<span title="1">title 1<br></span>
<span title="2">title 2<br></span>
<span title="3">title 3<br></span>
<span title="4">title 4<br></span>
<span title="5">title 5<br></span>
<span title="6">title 6<br></span>
```

### Option 2: radio button version

```js
$('.chb').click(function() {
  var input_id = this.id;
  var previousValue = $(this).data('storedValue');

  if (previousValue) {
    $(this).prop('checked', !previousValue);
    $(this).data('storedValue', !previousValue);
    $('span').show();
  } else {
    $(this).data('storedValue', true);
    $("input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").data("storedValue", false);
    $('span[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();
    $('span[title="' + input_id + '"]').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" id="1" class="chb">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="2" class="chb">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3" id="3" class="chb">3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="4" id="4" class="chb">4<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="5" id="5" class="chb">5<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="6" id="6" class="chb">6
</form>

<span title="1">title 1<br></span>
<span title="2">title 2<br></span>
<span title="3">title 3<br></span>
<span title="4">title 4<br></span>
<span title="5">title 5<br></span>
<span title="6">title 6<br></span>
```

## Updated version:

Using `this.check` to determine if a checkbox is checked.

Using `siblings()` to uncheck all other checkboxes.

```js
$('.chb').click(function() {
  var input_id = this.id;
  var _this = $(this);
  
  //uncheck, show everything
  if (!this.checked) {
    $('li').show();
    _this.siblings().prop('checked', false);
  } else {
  //check, show selected, hide others
    $('li[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();
    $('li[title="' + input_id + '"]').show();
    _this.siblings().prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="1" id="1" class="chb">1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="2" id="2" class="chb">2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="3" id="3" class="chb">3
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="4" id="4" class="chb">4
</form>

<li class="clan" title="1">
  <a class="noselect"></a>
  <div class="clan_content">
    some cotent 1
  </div>
</li>
<li class="clan" title="2">
  <a class="noselect"></a>
  <div class="clan_content">
    some cotent 2
  </div>
</li>
<li class="clan" title="3">
  <a class="noselect"></a>
  <div class="clan_content">
    some cotent 3
  </div>
</li>
<li class="clan" title="4">
  <a class="noselect"></a>
  <div class="clan_content">
    some cotent 4
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Note to OP: Makes more sense to use radio buttons (Since anyways you cannot uncheck the currently checked one - at least with this suggested code)

Comment: P.S: `$(this).attr('id')` or simply `this.id`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, radio button should be better

Comment: @DanielH Reason why I used check boxes because i need to be able to uncheck all and in that case everything will be visible. TY!

Comment: @TarGet Cool, if my solution solved your problem, please accept it =D thanks!

Comment: @DanielH How to make it now that if noone is checked, everything can show.

Comment: @TarGet check the updated one, you can uncheck the checkbox now

Comment: @DanielH You are a god.

Answer (score 1):

[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) & [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) are methods. You are calling them wrong. Please check the updated answer

```
$('.chb').click(function() {
    var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.chb').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $('span[title!="' + input_id + '"]').hide();
    $('span[title="'+ input_id + '"]').show();
});
```